# Standard Manager loaded instead of DeltaManager

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

We have websites running on Tomcat. Some of them are clustered (typically two nodes in a cluster), and it all works fine.

However, we have one pair where the sessions are not replicated correctly, even though the config appears to be similar to our other (working) installations.

When I examine the Tomcat nodes via JMX, I see that Cluster.modelerType is set to org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster for both working and non-working sites.

However, when I look at the Manager, I see that DeltaManager is loaded for the working nodes, but StandardManager is loaded for the node that is not working.

The web.xml does have "<distributable/>" set. Also, "<manager/>" is COMMENTED in context.xml. So, those two are not the issue.

Here is a snippet from server.xml (Tomcat 7.0.42)

```
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster" channelSendOptions="8">
   <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
     <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
      address="228.0.3.4"
      port="23810"
      frequency="500"
      dropTime="3000" 
     />
     <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"    
            address="192.168.1.144"
     />    
   </Channel>
</Cluster>
```

Any ideas what part of the configuration might cause SimpleTcpCluster to be active, but StandardManager to be in use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that what fixed it was adding metadata-complete="true" in our web.xml file.

This seems to be required on our sites that have servlet spec set to 3.0 (not reqd. on 2.5)

Without this, something that is being loaded (I'm guessing from some 3rd party jar we use) is probably un-doing the "distributable". it turns out that is one of the 3-rd party libraries we use includes a web-tag fragment, but does not also say it is "distributable", then the whole app isn't.

> The Servlet spec 3.0, section 8.2.3, 5.g.ix says:The web.xml resulting
>   from the merge is considered <distributable> only if all its web
>   fragments are marked as  as well.
>   [Servlet spec 3.1](https://java.net/downloads/servlet-spec/Public%20Review/servlet-3.1-pdr-draft.pdf)

Comment: Along with already having a distributable tag, I added the metadata-complete val to the web-apps tag in web.xml, and it did not fix the problem for me. So apparently there are multiple ways to have this issue. I'm seeing it on one Windows-based tomcat, but another Unix-based one with the exact same server.xml and webapp is getting the ____ does not implement ClusterManager warning. Really wish I understood where the hell it's getting the wrong value.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code in StandardContext (taken from Tomcat 8 but it hasn't really changed for a number of versions) that creates the Manager

```
// Acquire clustered manager
Manager contextManager = null;
Manager manager = getManager();
if (manager == null) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug(sm.getString("standardContext.cluster.noManager",
                Boolean.valueOf((getCluster() != null)),
                Boolean.valueOf(distributable)));
    }
    if ( (getCluster() != null) && distributable) {
        try {
            contextManager = getCluster().createManager(getName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("standardContext.clusterFail", ex);
            ok = false;
        }
    } else {
        contextManager = new StandardManager();
    }
}
```

It looks like you have checked the right things. At this point I'd connect up my IDE to the Tomcat instance and use remote debugging to step through this part of the code to figure out why the wrong Manager is being used.